# How to disable print option for particular user in document library in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a folder in the Document library.

It has been shared with two group of users(after breaking inherit permissions).

I wanted first group to able to print the documents but **not the second group**. I understand that, I can disable print option using IRM.

But it disabling at complete folder level.

So, when the first group member login, they are unable to print as IRM disabled it. How to achieve it for selective group members?

Please help.